# Why Geofences needs location manager in order to be triggered?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, android-geofence

I need to create a geofence with certain location and radius. That specific geofence is not triggered if i don't request location updates with `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` on only `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` priority, the other one's does not working. On every time when a location request is available and geofence need to changed status, is triggered. If i don't request updates, geofence is not triggered. Geofence has an `IntentService` to listen on geofence changes and Geofence is created into a `Service` in order to handle app force stop and reboot. Also it works only on GPS, mobile network and wi-fi are not triggered.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, if possible please can you try to rephrase your question (I appreciate English isn't your first language). Without Location services (and having the corresponding privileges) the location will not be know and hence the Geofence will never know when you're inside it. You only need High Accuracy if your Geofence is relatively small.

Comment: What i'm saying is geofences are triggered only when i set a location listener, with LocationServices. If i don't set it, geofences are not triggered. And yes, English is not my first language.

Comment: I think his question is clear (but I have the same issue, so maybe because of that it is clear to me ;) ). When you set a geofence, it only triggers if you attach a listener via requestLocationUpdates. I also heard it triggers when Google Maps is open, so it seems it doesn't matter who is requesting location updates. I have to be able to get updates while the app is in background or even killed. This works when I start a listener, but it troubles me that this one stays alive! (I keep seeing logging)

Comment: I tested on my phone and it Works without location listener, but sometimes. I think is because radius is to small and network location is jumping from a point to another one and geofence event is not triggered. On emulator it Works only with location listener.